# Export CSV from controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, controller

how to export queries from the controller and the results data from the controller not from database?

ex:

```
switch ($tipe) {

            case 'car':

            $totaldata2 =  \DB::select(\DB::raw("
                SELECT $flag as label,
                COUNT(tr.id) as data
                FROM driver tr
                LEFT JOIN vw_driver vw ON vw.id = tr.id
                WHERE tr.service= 'C'
                $where 
                GROUP BY $flag
                ORDER BY $flag asc
                "));
```

I expect the export CSV from the result data above is

`period_count,"status_label","status_data","service_label","service_data"`

Comment: what is `period_count,"status_label","status_data","service_label","service_data"`. what is `$flag`, `$where`?

Answer (score 0):

This package is the best tool to import/export data with Laravel, check that out:

https://laravel-excel.com/